# could not retrieve mail on android using javamail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I made ​​a code retrieve mail using javamail in android, but it does not successfully retrieve mail, but there is no error. with the same code, I can retrieve mail with Netbean IDE. Can someone help me?

My function: readMail.java

---

public class readMail extends Authenticator{

```
private String subjek;

public Message[] getReadMail() throws MessagingException{

        String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

        String username = "someuser@gmail.com";
        String password = "somepassword";

        Properties pop3Props = new Properties();

        pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port",  "995");
        pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");

        URLName url = new URLName("pop3", "pop.gmail.com", 995, "", username, password);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props, null);
        Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);
        store.connect();

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

        return messages;
}

public void setSubjek(String subjek){
    this.subjek = subjek;
}

public String getsubjek(){
    return subjek;
}
```

}

---

My Activity: MainActivity.java

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    TextView subjek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subjek);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        readMail readmail = new readMail();
        Message[] messages = new Message[] { };
        messages = readmail.getReadMail();

        for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++){
        subjek.setText(messages[1].getSubject());
        }
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gagal koneksi ke server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

See the [JavaMail debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to get started.

Also, you can [get rid of the socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

And you might want to look at these [Gmail examples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).